# Выводит в компиляторе вместо числа nan

Tags: c++, списки, nan

Создан список из чисел 3 5 1 9

```
struct Data

  {   int a;
    };

    struct List
    {   Data d;
    List *next;
    };


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        List *u = NULL;
        // 1 uzel
        u = new List; // obyavlenie 
        u->d.a = 3;  
        u->next = NULL; // ukazatel na sled element
        // dlya udobstva sozd peremennuyu-ukazatel kotoraya hranit adress posl elementa
        List *x;
        // 2 uzel
        x = u;
        x->next = new List;
        x = x->next;
        x->d.a = 5;
        x->next = NULL;
        // 
        List *c;
        // 3 uzel
        c = x;
        c->next = new List;
        c = c->next;
        c->d.a = 1;
        c->next = NULL;
        //
        List *b;
        // 4 uzel
        b = c;
        b->next = new List;
        b = b->next;
        b->d.a = 9;
        b->next = NULL;
        // Vivod (prosto idem po spisku)
        while(u)
        {
            cout << u->d.a << endl; 
            u = u->next;         
        }
```

Добавлена функция подсчета среднего арифметического, но вместо числа в компиляторе выводится `Average = nan`:

```
// srednee arifm
int sum = 0, count = 0;
while(u)
{
    sum += u->d.a; 
    ++count;
}
cout << "Average = " << double(sum)/count << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

**Почему?**

Comment: Не в компиляторе оно выводится, а в процессе работы. Не надо путать.

Comment: А у вас есть отладчик? Вот им и воспользуйтесь. Вангую, что вы делите ноль на ноль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При таком коде:

```
while(u)
{
    sum += u->d.a; 
    ++count;
}
```

u в цикле не меняется, поэтому мы получим бесконечный цикл, если `u != 0` либо, если `u == 0` совсем не зайдем в цикл, и в дальнейшем получим деление нуля на ноль, что в результате дает значение "не является числом" (Not-a-Number, NaN).

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

К операциям, приводящим к появлению NaN в качестве ответа, относятся:

- ...
- деление нуля на ноль

[Подробнее о делении нуля на нуль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)

`u` в Вашем коде равен нулю потому, что в цикле вывода Вы его меняете:

```
while(u)
{
   cout << u->d.a << endl; 
   u = u->next;         
}
```

после этого цикла `u` будет равен нулю.

Для исправления чуть переделаем код:

```
  // Vivod (prosto idem po spisku)
  List *p = u;//введем указатель, который будем использовать для прохода по списку перед выводом
  while (p) {//В цикле работаем только с p, а не с u
    cout << p->d.a << endl;
    p = p->next;
  }
  // srednee arifm
  if (u) {//Список не пуст
    int sum = 0, count = 0;
    p = u;//снова ставим p в равным u, для прохода с начала списка
    while(p)//в цикле также работаем с p, а не с u
    {
      sum += p->d.a; 
      ++count;
      p = p->next;//не забываем перейти к следующему элементу
    }
    cout << "Average = " << double(sum)/count << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Empty list" << endl;
  }
```

Также Вы забыли про освобождение памяти.
Но в любом случае, Ваш список - это подход, скорее, для языка C, а не для C++.

Comment: вы можете подсказать как это исправить в коде?

Comment: @DenSimachov добавил в ответ

Comment: очень сильно благодарю! все доступно и понятно!!! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если программа будет в этом цикле то очевидно что она из него не выйдет никогда.
т.к. прога его прошла значит u=nullptr; а 0/0=nan (а для флоат краш)

```
while(u)
{
    sum += u->d.a; 
    ++count;
}
cout << "Average = " << double(sum)/count << endl;
```

может ты подучишь с++ перед тем как создавать проект? хотя бы про дебаггинг. а то уже 5 вопросов за 2 дня.